# How to obtain the remainder in float data type using modulus operator

Tags: javascript

In javascript, the modulus operator is used to obtain the remainder of a mathematical expression. The result obtained is always an integer. What is the function that is to be used to obtain the exact decimal value remainder in this case?

Comment: The same function. The result *is not* always an integer.

Comment: `1123.25 % 5 = 3.25`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but note that as @GerardoFurtado mentions, `%`'s result is not always a whole number: `32.5 % 10` is `2.5`. *(I say "not a whole number" rather than "not an integer" because even if it were a whole number, it would still be a double.)

Comment: Do take into consideration that javascript uses floating points so some results may be misleading, for example ```49.90 % 0.10 = 0.09999999999999581 ``` but the expected answer to that is ```0```

Answer (score 2):

This is working just fine using the `%` operator:

```js
console.log(12.5 % 10) // 2.5
console.log(10 % 5.5)  // 4.5
```

For a reference, also see the [MDN article on the remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()), outlining this behavior.